# Google Closure compiler - How to print errors?

Tags: google-closure-compiler

A simple question..

I'm running this command:

java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties -client -d64 -jar ./closure-compiler-v20180610.jar --js ./some.js  --compilation_level ADVANCED --js_output_file ./out.js --warning_level VERBOSE --logging_level FINEST --formatting=pretty_print

After a while, it prints a huge amount of generated JS to stdout and then it adds this:

12 error(s), 18 warning(s)

But where are those warnings / errors? I can't find them anywhere. The generated log file also doesn't contain them..

How can I print the detailed error messages?

Answer (score 1):

Errors print to standard error whereas js prints to standard out. They can be piped to separate locations.

Answer (score 0):

Wow never mind.. it prints the errors too, but because of the huge amount of JS I didn't see the messages...